# Why did I get "undefined method"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I have a profile model, and a user has_one profile.

Here's my route:

```
resources :users
resources :profiles
```

Here's the show method in my controller:

```
def show
  @profile = @user.profile
end
```

Why do I get this error when I try to access the show view:

```
NoMethodError in ProfilesController#show

undefined method `profile' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the `@user` instance variable. You probably want to do something like this:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @profile = @user.profile
end
```

**Boring explanation:** Instance variables (the ones with `@` in the front) are `nil` by default. They can be de facto "instantiated" by just assigning a non-nil value to it. Here, `@user` is an instance variable, and it points to nil because it hasn't been assigned anything. `profile` is invoked in the context of `nil`, which doesn't have a `profile` method, so you get the no method exception. This is as opposed to local variables, starting with a lower-cased letter, which would in this case have raised a local variable not found exception.

Comment: now i get this error: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProfilesController#show

Couldn't find User with ID=2`

Comment: ok that is because the user does not exist, try passing in some other id and it should work

Comment: Well this will depend on your implementation. I don't know how your models are structured. I only inferred from your use of `@user` that there was some backend `User` that had a `#profile` method.

Comment: @Justin: You mention that you're logged in as the user. How are you "logged in"? Have you used some gem like Authlogic to handle your login? If you show your "login" code, we can point you to the variable (or method) you want to use.

Comment: I used RESTful sessions to log in

Comment: In traditional REST-style routing, unless you're doing something special, `UsersController#show` would show the user's profile. There's no need to have a separate `ProfilesController`.

Comment: @Justin: I'm not familiar with the *RESTful sessions* gem/plugin. If you point me to the documentation, I can help you dig through it and find the method you should be using to fetch the currently logged in user.

Comment: it's ok to have the same controller for users and profiles, even though they have different models?

Comment: oh, the currently logged in user is current_user, and I can use it anywhere

Comment: What's the association between the User and Profile model? Can a user have multiple profiles? At the end of the day, what do you want `ProfilesController#show` to do?

Comment: A user has one profile, and a profile belongs to a user. I want a profile to have it's own show method where you can view the profile. Right now I'm creating the link in the header that points the the user's own profile.

Comment: you could use `current_user.profile` if you wanted the profile for current_user

Comment: That's what I use for the link: `<%= link_to "Profile", profile_path(current_user.profile) %>` I'm concerned with the controller now and making the view work.

Comment: ok I see what's going on... it's the link that's not working, it brings me to the profile of the user with id = 2... if I manually go to my own profile it works

Comment: It would appear based on your link that `current_user` is a method that returns the currently logged in user, but since this is specified in the `profile_path` argument, the final link will just be to the `Profile`'s id. You can probably look this up in the `ProfilesController` the normal way: `@profile Profile.find(params[:id])`. There's no need to invoke `@user` in the `ProfilesController#show` method. If you need it in the specific view, call the association in the view. If you need `@user` to be instantiated for a global layout, move that to the `ApplicationController`.

Comment: You used `current_user` in your sample link.

Answer (score 0):

Because `@user` object is `nil`? Did you populate `@user` instance variable before trying to use it?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the @user is nil, you need something like this

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
  @profile = @user.profile
end
```